# Understanding the order in new[]

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I understand that the usage of `new[]` is: `new <type>[<size>]`.
Now, suppose I'd like to allocate a matrix with the number of columns `nCols` known at compile time. In terms of the above usage, `type` is `int[nCols]`. So, I would think to write:

```
const int nCols = 5;
int nRows;
cin >> nRows;
int (*matrix)[nCols] = new (int[nCols]) [nRows];
```

How come the correct way of writing it is actually `new int[nRows][nCols]`?

Comment: `using arr = int[nCols]; auto* matrix = new arr[nRows];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How come the correct way of writing it is actually new `int[nRows][nCols]`?

Simply put, because you’re allowed to put parentheses around expressions (`1 + 1` and `(1 + 1)` are both valid and evaluate to the same), but you are *not* allowed to put parentheses around arbitrary types (`int` is a valid type but `(int)` isn’t).

Parentheses inside a type name always have have a semantic function (e.g. declaring a function pointer), they don’t just group. [cppreference has an example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) illustrating this:

> ```
> new int(*[10])(); // error: parsed as (new int) (*[10]) ()
> new (int (*[10])()); // okay: allocates an array of 10 pointers to functions
> ```

---

Furthermore, the syntax for writing type declarations (inherited from C) works in [outwards-directed clockwise spirals](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Note that the variable you want to allocate storage for is declared as

```
int (*matrix)[nCols]
```

The variable is the *innermost* part. And, lastly, pointer *access* in C (and C++) mirrors pointer *declaration*. Therefore, the `new[]` expression mirrors the declaration syntax and, since you want to allocate `nRow` static arrays, the number of elements you are allocating is dropped into the position of the pointer declaration (`(*matrix)`).

---

I advise *against* writing such code in C++. First off, use `constexpr` instead of `const` here, although in this particular case bare `const` remains valid.

But more importantly, you almost(?) never want to use `new`. Instead of manually allocating an array, use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int[nCols]> matrix(nRows);
// or:
std::vector<std::array<int, nCols>> matrix(nRows);
```

Comment: Can you store an array in a vector like that?

Comment: Hmm alright yeah looks alright. Won't be able to `push_back` or anything but that's okay here. Keep forgetting that container value_type requirements are per-op mostly

Answer (score 2):

It's to be consistent with an ordinary array declaration and array indexing.

Note `T array[M][N];` also declares an array of `M` arrays, each with size `N`, just like what's created by `new T[M][N]`.

Now think about the expression `a[i][j]`, where `a` is either an array of `M` arrays, each with size `N`, or a pointer to the first array element in such an array:

```
extern int a[M][N];
// OR
extern int b[M][N];
int (*a)[N] = b;
// OR
int (*a)[N] = new int[M][N];
```

To evaluate `a[i][j]`, we first apply subscript `i`, then subscript `j`. This just makes sense from the order they appear, plus the expression parses as `(a[i])[j]`.  The subexpression `a[i]` will be the `i`-th subarray of type `int[N]`, so `i` may range from `0` to `M-1`. Once we have that subarray, the valid `j` indices are from `0` to `N-1`. So to make the order of the indices match up with the array declaration or `new` syntax, the language chooses to specify them so that the "top-level" dimension is first: `T[M][N]` means "array of `M` arrays of `N` objects of type `T`".

Yes, this does mean things may be a bit surprising when using a type alias: if `ArrT` is `T[X]`, then `ArrT[Y]` is `T[Y][X]`. But type aliases definitely don't work like text substitutions anyway (for another example, if `Ptr` is `int*`, `const Ptr` is `int *const` and not `const int*`).